# I would like to count number of values for dynamically created week number column

Tags: mysql

i have a table emp_sample with fields emp_code,alloc_date,alloc_hrs.I would like to display the total number of allocated hours for every week with year and week number as their column names dynamically for any number of records in mysql procedure
Here is my code

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
  (CONCAT ('MAX(CASE WHEN alloc_date=''',
         alloc_date, 
         ''' THEN concat(alloc_hrs) END) `',
       year(alloc_date),date_format(alloc_date,'%b'),week(alloc_date),
         'week`'
         ))
 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM emp_sample;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT emp_code, ', @sql,' FROM emp_sample group by emp_code');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I want my output like

```
emp_code        julweek30 julweek31  ......
2145                 5       3
2146                 4       2
```

That is the value should be the count(alloc_date) for each emp_code for every  week.I want this to be done only with mysql

Comment: define your output which you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8165986/bhargav i have given the output could you please help me with this

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to temporarily store the result of the first query and use it to form the second, I would recommend the following:

- Change the first query so that it returns both `alloc_date` and `label` in the result, and not just the `alloc_date`, e.g.:

  `date     | label
  31/7/2017 | julweek31`
- Get the result in memory (with php/java code)
- Iterate through the result and dynamically generate the second query. For each row in the first result, there will be an inner `SELECT` statement in the second query, e.g.:

  `SELECT es.emp_code,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_sample WHERE emp_code = es.emp_code AND alloc_date = <date_of_row_1>) AS <label_of_row_1>
  FROM emp_sample es
  GROUP BY es.emp_code`

  Number of inner `SELECT` statement will be equal to number of rows retuened by the first query.

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: what  should i replace for <date_of_row_1>,<label_of_row_1>

Comment: i need this to be done only in mysql and further use this as a procedure

Comment: Well, in that case, you need to write a stored procedure and iterate through the result of first query

Comment: `<date_of_row_1>,<label_of_row_1>` will be the values you will get from the first query